# Why does the float default value is not 0.0f in java in the below code

Tags: java, floating-point

```
 public class Main
    {
        float fValue;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main obj=new Main();
            System.out.println(obj.fValue);
        }
    }
```

Here the output is 0.0 and not 0.0f.Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Floats are not printed with an f at the end. The f suffix is for literals in code, not for printing.

Comment: The f suffix just tells the compiler to initialize the value as a float.  Printing the f would be pointless because, as the programmer, you already know that you're printing out a float.  You're the one who specified a float when you set the type of your variable.  The only piece of information you should be interested in is the value, so that's what Java prints out for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the "f" used after a float's digits is actually used in creation time so as to mark the value as a float.
Eg. The number 123.45f is a float as it has been marked by an "f".
The number 123.45d is a double, as it is marked by "d".
Example, see the two cases below

Instantiating a float variable

```
float floatVariable = 123.45f;
```

Passing a float variable to a method.

method declaration:

```
void printFloat(float floatValue){
     System.out.println(floatValue);
}
```

method call:

```
printFloat(floatVariable);
printFloat(123.45f);
```

All values with decimal digits are by default double, and all numbers without decimal digits are by default integers. The "f" is required to declare the number as float.

```
printFloat((float)12345);
```

Above, you will have to cast to float because `12345` is an integer.

```
printFloat((float)123.45)
```

Above, you will have to cast to float because `123.45` is a double.

```
printFloat(123.45f);
```

Excellent!

At the other hand, printing the variable only prints the value. It is not a case of creation, so no necessary qualifier is needed.